# Close or open circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, charge

A electric source provides a non electrostatic influence on the charges inside the source which pushes the positive charges from the negative terminal to the positive one. Does this happen when the source is part of a close circuit or of an open one?

Comment: what do you mean by "a non electrostatic influence "  ? If the circuit is open and energy is not leaking, things are static and there has to be an "electrostatic influence" right ?

Answer (score 0):

Actually the source is capable of creating field around it .The imaginary field lines pass preferably through the circuit(I don't remember that if it was called permeability or somewhat ) and exert force on charges to flow .If the circuit is open it not possible to go to the other side due to resistance offered by the air between. Actually if voltage (the field) is high and distance between the ends in conductor is small (lower resistance)charges can jump the open circuit by overcoming the forces and flow. We do it every other day in welding workshop when bring close the torch to metal workpiece nothing happens but when you bring it too close charge jump through air. one more thing Don't think I am a welder I am an engineering student.

Answer (score -1):

I know it is the back electromotive force in a circuit carrying coil for which such case occurs. Most electrical components carry coil , that's why back emf occurs in open or close loop circuits because every coil discharging current must produce magnetic field and such fields comes with polarity and will likely attract or repel neighbouring   fields.

Comment: Your phrases seem to be a little off. Could you clean this up by clarifying your answer?